# Where is --spring.output.ansi.enabled configured?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I have inherited a java Spring Boot project and I'm new to most java configurations. When I run this application in debug mode the first argument passed to my application as `args[0]` is `--spring.output.ansi.enabled=always`. I have searched my project files but cannot see where this might be configured to turn off, that is I do not want it passed in as an argument. I am using the Spring **STS 3.9.1** IDE.

Answer (score 12):

Under Debug Configuration, uncheck the field highlighted in Red.[image: Debug Configuration]

Comment: This happens in the current very starter project for Consuming WS (discovered by a colleague of mine, credit due).

Comment: Good catch @andy

Comment: Many Thanks for your valuable Answer.

Answer (score 11):

In the Spring STS IDE the Debug Configuration has an option `ANSI console output` which was checked. Unchecking stopped the argument being passed.

Answer (score 2):

All previous answers are correct. Nevertheless, here another alternative to configure Ansi output, even though it does not answer the original question (remember, `args[0]` had a value): the environment variable `SPRING_OUTPUT_ANSI_ENABLED=always` could be set, either in the STS/Eclipse run/debug configuration (tab `Environment`), or otherwise for your account, or globally on your machine.

By the way, any Spring Boot configuration property can be configured via environment variables:

- either in a [SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON environment variable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.application-json),
- or with [Binding from Environment Variables](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding.environment-variables)

Answer (score 1):

You can put any Spring Boot configuration properties into your `application.properties` (see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files)).

Or you can use any of the other mechanisms to externalize your configuration properties (see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config)).